# C++ template specialization problems

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have problems with specialized function templates in C++. I'm writing a comparison function template which will be used in sorting different data types. Here is part of my code:

```
template < typename T >
bool cmp(T a, T b)
{
    std::cout<<"normal"<<std::endl;
    return(a >= b);
}

template < typename T >
bool cmp(T* a, T* b)
{
    std::cout<<"pointer"<<std::endl;
    return(*a >= *b);
}
```

so I could sort by values and by pointed values. However, when I try to pass this function into `sort`:

```
double* double_array[]={d1,d2,d3,d4,d5};
nsp::sort(double_array, 5, nsp::cmp<double*>);
```

I get the compile error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'sort(double* [5], int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'|
template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
could not resolve address from overloaded function 'cmp<double*>'|
```

Why? I am explicitly providing the template type!

For reference, my sort function template looks like:

```
namespace nsp {
    ...

    template < typename T, typename CMP>
    void sort(T array[], int n, CMP cmp=CMP())
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < n-1; j++)
            for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
              if(cmp(array[i],array[i + 1]))
                  std::swap(array[i], array[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question. There is problem with using right compare function of both.

Comment: I have also specializations for c-strings etc. My homework is to write a sort template with specializations for: pointers, c-strings, and adresses. Second and third work as they are char* and void* and can be easily specialized.

Comment: Are you missing a namespace nsp around cmp?

Comment: No, all is in namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting a compile error with "unresolved overloaded function type" is because, quite simply, you are trying to pass an overloaded function to `sort()`. You provide `cmp<double*>` but there are still *two* `cmp<double*>` functions: the fun that takes two `double*`s (your first function template) and the one that takes two `double**`s (your second). It's unclear to the compiler which one you mean.

You could just cast `cmp` to the one that you want:

```
static_cast<bool(*)(double*, double*)>(nsp::cmp<double>) // note you want cmp<double>,
                                                         // not cmp<double*>
```

Note that one source of confusion is that you think you are *specializing* `cmp`. You are not. There is no partial specializations of function templates. You overloaded it. The only allowed specializations of function templates are *explicit*:

```
template <>
bool cmp(double* a, double* b) {
    std::cout<<"pointer"<<std::endl;
    return(*a >= *b);
}
```

That would make `nsp::cmp<double*>` unambiguous and would do exactly what you would expect. In this case. You would have to do this for every type separately. Instead, you could provide a class template comparator because class templates *can* be partially specialized:

```
template <typename T> struct Cmp { .. };     // "normal"
template <typename T> struct Cmp<T*> { .. }; // "pointer"
```

That way, you can just pass `nsp::Cmp<double*>()`, which is in my opinion much cleaner.

Comment: Spot on answer, +1 I first though OP is trying to pass a function where a functor was expected. I'd still prefer to use a functor for these kind of stuff (or of course a lambda). This way, one is not tricked anymore into "partially specializing functions" (which in fact are just overloads).

Comment: I thought it was the problem. So I need two sorting functions? One normal and one for pointers where I would cast functor with given by you?

Comment: @AA I didn't understand any of that. Your `sort` takes a comparator, you need to pass in *one* *specific* comparator to do that. The easiest way to handle that is to make your comparator a functor, as I mentioned, because then you don't run into the problem you ran into.

Comment: @AA the problem is that you pass the name of the function as a template parameter to `sort`. The compiler doesn't know which function you intend to call by just looking at the name `cmp`, unless you explicitly tell him the type.

Comment: Okay, now everyting works. I have struct templates as you posted. Thank you very much.